# Rails send_data streaming PDF as bytes, unless route accessed directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, amazon-s3

I've got a simple Rails app that downloads a PDF from a (private) S3 bucket and serves it to the browser.

```ruby
# app/controllers/file_controller.rb
class FileController < ApplicationController
  def send_pdf
    s3_file = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
      region: "us-east-1",
      access_key_id: S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secret_access_key: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    ).bucket('bucket-name').objects({prefix: "file_name"}).first.get.body.string

    send_data s3_file, filename: "FileName.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
  end
end


# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'file', to: 'file#send_pdf', defaults: { format: 'pdf' }
end
```

- When accessing the route directly via URL, it displays the PDF fine.
- When opening a link to the route in a new tab, it displays the PDF fine.
- When opening a link in the same tab, the PDF data streams as text to the browser instead.

The same behavior occurs in Rails 4 and 5.

I'm probably missing something annoyingly minor here, but how can I get the open in the same tab behavior to properly display the PDF instead of streaming bytes as text?

---

**Update 1:**

Chrome gives a `Failed to load PDF document` error when `send_pdf` is modified to use `send_file` instead of `send_data`. (This error happens regardless of link click or direct route request.)

```ruby
def send_pdf

  # S3 download

  temp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/file.pdf"

  File.open(temp_file,"wb") do |f|
    f.write(s3_file)
    f.close
  end

  send_file temp_file, filename: "FileName.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'

  File.delete(temp_file)
end
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a working solution to this? I'm having the same issues

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `send_file` instead of `send_data`?
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file

Comment: I did try that, but got a different error (please see Update 1). Possibly that'd be easier to resolve than the behavior with `send_data`?